# R ggplot log log scale

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, scale

I have a plot and I would like to convert it into log log scale. I have tried different solution but none of them didn't create right log log plot.

The original plot looks like this
[image]

and I used this script to plot it.

```
plot(ggplot(data=the.table[[i]],aes(x=the.table[[i]]$friends_count,y=the.table[[i]]$degree.in))+
labs(x="Friends Count",y="Degree In")+
       geom_point(color="#56B4E9")+ggtitle(paste(i,"Degree In-Friends Count",collapse="")))
```

The difference between values on the x and y axis are really huge so I would like to plot it with log log scale

[image]

I have searched stcakoverflow to find a solution and I changed the script like this.

```
plot(ggplot(data=the.table[[i]],aes(x=the.table[[i]]$friends_count,y=the.table[[i]]$degree.in))+
         scale_x_log10(limits = c(1, NA), 
                       labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)),
                       breaks=trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x, n=6)) +
         scale_y_log10(limits = c(1, NA),
                       labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)),
                       breaks=trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x, n=6)) +
         labs(x="Friends Count",y="Degree In")+
       geom_point(color="#56B4E9")+ggtitle(paste(i,"Degree In-Friends Count",collapse="")))
```

It produced plot with this warning messages:

```
Warning messages:
1: In scale$trans$trans(x) : NaNs produced
2: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

Do you have any suggestion? Thanks.

I have put sample data in case you need it:

```
structure(list(screen_name = structure(c(70L, 29L, 91L, 37L, 
99L, 33L, 46L, 26L, 63L, 48L, 80L, 17L, 15L, 89L, 88L, 82L, 69L, 
77L, 30L, 12L, 58L, 93L, 64L, 65L, 67L, 41L, 62L, 10L, 74L, 76L, 
1L, 9L, 47L, 35L, 24L, 14L, 71L, 72L, 34L, 23L, 39L, 11L, 52L, 
57L, 86L, 22L, 100L, 3L, 2L, 53L, 78L, 36L, 97L, 84L, 90L, 8L, 
45L, 38L, 50L, 55L, 96L, 61L, 13L, 16L, 43L, 60L, 85L, 32L, 20L, 
83L, 66L, 59L, 56L, 94L, 54L, 31L, 73L, 79L, 18L, 44L, 40L, 4L, 
27L, 19L, 92L, 95L, 75L, 21L, 25L, 6L, 28L, 87L, 7L, 51L, 81L, 
68L, 5L, 42L, 49L, 98L), .Label = c("_Anahtar_", "_fani__", "_uzumce", 
"28BeyzaTosun", "2cerkesoglu", "34fuzuli34RT", "abatila", "Adimozr", 
"AforizmaYazar", "ahmetfuadi", "Ak_ekip_rt", "Ak_Ekip_Rte", "ak_parti_tt", 
"AkgenclikBerlin", "AkGercekler", "AkkulisAK", "Akparti_AkRTE", 
"akreperol1955", "AlparslanTurk06", "aozturk70", "asimm4th", 
"ASLAN__5", "AyAzyahu", "bavehayran", "bbulentkayar", "be_yaz_ca", 
"BennKerem", "BerilDeniz77", "bilalardic_", "billpostmus", "bizimmmemleket", 
"BULUT__USTASI", "BurakFBSensoy", "cayelirize", "CicekciKiz_", 
"DobraUzunAdam", "DogrulariYaziyo", "ebaabil", "efendi_insan", 
"Elmanoglu_Drvs", "emre_izmir_", "ErsoyMehmetAkf", "esma_fb_3437", 
"esrefynbsn", "fatihcaglayan25", "favlasanaa", "FenaYazar", "filiz_paker", 
"GabrielAydin", "gonul_insani_", "HanZala32", "holy_sin", "InstagramPlus", 
"IsmetOnc", "KaankutAatay", "kamilekucuker24", "karikatu_r", 
"KemalAta34", "kiliskilis79", "KIRMIZI_BEY4Z_G", "MahirAytekin", 
"MakarnaSos", "MarkGKirshner", "MazlumunFedaisi", "MercanSureyya", 
"MerterSibel", "MoRHoPi", "muhacir1887", "NormanBuffong", "oncevatan81", 
"OrbisTertius3", "osmanlit0runu", "Oyuna_GelmeTR", "ResmiZaytung", 
"rt_liyorum", "RTerdog4n", "RTErdog4n", "Saglam_Iradee", "Sanki_biri", 
"Semih_Kural", "sessiz_ciglik0", "sevdamizzz", "sezerhsn", "siyaset__name", 
"Siyasi_Yazar", "son3er", "Sussam_Olmuyor_", "Telefizyon", "trakyali77", 
"twit_komedyeni", "TwitineGeldim", "uguronal", "ultrasKan1071", 
"yakupaltinoz", "Yazar212", "YEA1453", "Yn1Dunya", "Yobaz_Zeynep", 
"Yobaz4K", "zekibahce"), class = "factor"), degree.in = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 35L, 0L, 0L, 12L, 0L, 71L, 0L, 29L, 0L, 
0L, 330L, 0L, 0L, 207L, 0L, 2L, 337L, 0L, 23L, 0L, 113L, 0L, 
112L, 19L, 0L, 0L, 29L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 10L, 13L, 9L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 26L, 0L, 185L, 0L, 285L, 0L, 49L, 152L, 0L, 0L, 11L, 96L, 
1324L, 45L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 1110L, 0L, 0L, 38L, 0L, 40L, 0L, 4L, 
7L, 0L, 13L, 103L, 0L, 40L, 65L, 12L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 562L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 225L, 0L, 0L, 93L, 0L, 70L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 4L), friends_count = c(549982L, 360141L, 292551L, 264835L, 
192642L, 190477L, 153839L, 127660L, 126163L, 124043L, 115284L, 
113246L, 109422L, 107159L, 105183L, 101006L, 100667L, 99427L, 
98606L, 97909L, 95053L, 94830L, 92558L, 90112L, 89117L, 88388L, 
87969L, 87650L, 86907L, 85422L, 85395L, 84870L, 84747L, 83611L, 
83357L, 82381L, 82227L, 81084L, 80187L, 78807L, 76336L, 76231L, 
73940L, 73840L, 73759L, 73669L, 73324L, 73268L, 72944L, 72806L, 
71729L, 71208L, 70621L, 69982L, 69669L, 69432L, 69391L, 68880L, 
68478L, 67651L, 67514L, 66855L, 66472L, 66396L, 66309L, 65044L, 
64248L, 64038L, 63455L, 63275L, 62500L, 62388L, 61696L, 61212L, 
61154L, 61077L, 60700L, 60487L, 60426L, 60265L, 60264L, 58954L, 
58907L, 58903L, 58671L, 58086L, 57856L, 57793L, 57127L, 56910L, 
56508L, 56506L, 56466L, 56378L, 56343L, 56334L, 56314L, 56169L, 
55864L, 55858L)), .Names = c("screen_name", "degree.in", "friends_count"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -100L))
```

Comment: this might not solve your problem, but just a note that will help you when using ggplot2: if you declare that data=the.table[[i]], then when you declare things inside `aes`, don't re-write the data frame with `$` notation; just write the variable name `(data=the.table[[i]],aes(x=friends_count`) . it will be evaluated in the declared data frame environment. As it stands, you're sending it a vector, rather than simply letting it evaluate the variable correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sample data contains several entries with `degree.in` equal to zero. The logarithm of zero is `-Inf`, which is sometimes represented as `NA`. In any case it is not a meaningful value in a plot. I suggest that you make sure that all your data points have positive values if you want to represent them on log scale.

You may try to plot a corresponding subset of your data using, e.g.,

```
the.table_pos <- the.table[the.table$degree.in > 0,]
```

Comment: You're welcome; @eabanoz . I'm glad that I could help.

Comment: Hi RHertel, I used your suggestion and it gives this error.                       Error in ifelse(!is.na(scale$limits), scale$limits, scale$range$range) : 
  replacement has length zero
In addition: Warning message:
In rep(no, length.out = length(ans)) :
  'x' is NULL so the result will be NULL         .Do you have any idea?

Comment: Sorry - I'm not sure I can help. According to your `dput()` output it seems that your data is stored as a data frame. I thought it was a list. Unfortunately I have to leave now. The warning message was due to occurrences of `log(0)`. Maybe one could just live with this warning (it's not an error after all), or set the values that are zero to `NA`.

Comment: Hi RHertel, it was originally a list object but your code turns it into data frame. May main problem is even thought I get rid off all 0's plot continue to give the same error message.